# Understanding proof of $\mathcal P(A) \subseteq \mathcal P(B) \to A \subseteq B$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Working on Richard Hammock. "Book of Proof" (p. 162), appears the following proof:

> Example 8.9 
>   Suppose A and B are sets. If $\mathcal P(A) \subseteq \mathcal P(B) \to A \subseteq B$.
>
> Proof. We use direct proof. Assume $P(A) \subseteq \mathcal P(B)$.
>   Based on this assumption, we must now show that $A \subseteq B$.
>   To show $A \subseteq B$, suppose that $a \in A$.
>   Then the one-element set $\{a\}$ is a subset of $A$, so $\{a\} \in \mathcal P(A)$.
>   But then, since $P(A) \subseteq \mathcal P(B)$, it follows that $\{a\} \in \mathcal P(B)$.
>   This means that $\{a\} \subseteq B$, hence $a \in B$.
>   We’ve shown that $a \in A \to a \in B$, so therefore $A \subseteq B$.

As I understand, the definition of inclusion says that whenever an *arbitrary* element belongs to $\mathcal P(A)$, then that same element belongs to $\mathcal P(B)$. But the author talks about a *fixed* element *{a}*. Does this invalidate the proof ? Now, that element is not arbitrary — it is going to be a singleton set.

Comment: Is $a$ that is "arbitrary" (and not $\{ a \}$) in the sense that is an element of $A$ whatever. Thus, we can "generalize", i.e. the result holds **for every** element of $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypothesis that $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)$ says that every subset of $A$ is also a subset of $B$. In particular, every singleton subset of $A$ is a singleton subset of $B$. And as it happens, that part of the hypothesis is all that we need in order to conclude that every element of $A$ is also an element of $B$, i.e., that $A\subseteq B$.

The fact that we use only part of the hypothesis does not invalidate the argument. If it’s true that every subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$, then it’s certainly true that every singleton subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$; if the desired conclusion follows from that part of the hypothesis, it certainly follows from the whole hypothesis. More generally, if $P$ implies $Q$, and $Q$ implies $R$, then $P$ implies $R$. Here $P$ is the hypothesis that $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)$, $Q$ is the assertion that every singleton subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$, and $R$ is the assertion that $A\subseteq B$.

In fact in this case the hypothesis that $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)$ is actually equivalent to the statement that every singleton subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$. It would be a good exercise for you to try to prove that if every singleton subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$, then in fact $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)$.

Comment: Thanks Prof. Brian! This is such a fine answer, a quality answer. It is unbeliavable that someone downvote this type of answer. What is the discrepancy here? Is there a mistake? mind-blowing..

Comment: Thank you for this awesome answer, @Brian M. Scott. I did the exercises you proposed. Do you think it is correct ?

Proof:
Assume $\{a\} \in P(A)$.
Then, $\{a\} \subseteq A$ [by def. of $P(A)$]. As every subset of $A$ belongs to $B$ [by hypothesis], $\{a\}$ belongs to $B$. Hence, $\{a\} \in P(B)$ [by def. of $P(B)$].
Therefore, if every singleton subset of $A$ belongs to $B$ then $P(A)$ is a subset of $B$.

Comment: @F.Zer: You’re welcome. What you’ve proved in your comment is half of the exercise: your argument shows that if $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)$, then every singleton subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$. To finish proving the equivalence, you need to show that if every singleton subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$, then $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)$. So suppose that every singleton subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$, and let $X\in\wp(A)$. If $X=\varnothing$, then $X\in\wp(B)$ (why?). Otherwise, let $x\in X$; then $\{x\}$ is a singleton subset of $A$, so it’s a subset of $B$, and therefore $x\in B$. This shows ...

Comment: ... that every element of $X$ is an element of $B$, which means that $X\subseteq B$, i.e., $X\in\wp(B)$. $X$ was an arbitrary non-empty element of $\wp(A)$, and we already saw that $\varnothing\in\wp(B)$, so we’ve shown that $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)$.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it, @Brian M. Scoot.
Sorry, perhaps I am missing something but is it what I was proving. In my comment, I proved "if every singleton subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$, then $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$". Is that right ?

Comment: However, I do realise that missed to prove the other side of the equivalence. I need to show: "if $P(A) \subseteq P(B)$ then every singleton subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$".

Comment: @F.Zer: No, you proved that if $\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)$, then every singleton subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$. It’s the other direction that you’re missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106717/discussion-between-f-zer-and-brian-m-scott).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that might provide some clarity.

> Recall that $E\in\mathcal{P}(S)$ means $E\subseteq S$.
>
> Now, note that $A\in\mathcal{P}(A)$. Since
>   $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(B)$, it follows that
>   $A\in\mathcal{P}(B)$. This means that $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 0):

- You seem to assume that $a$ is some  fixed element, while it is, in fact, an " ***arbitrary*** " element.
- The author makes no assumption as to this object $a$ that would individuate it, or make it " special" in whatever way. He only assumes what is necessary for this object $a$ to do its job, namely, that $a$ is an element of $A$ ( implying that $\{a\}$ is an element of $P(A)$).
- This is a general technique in mathematics: considering, so to say,  ***generic individuals,*** that is, individuals capable of representing a whole class : what the author will prove about this arbitrary object $a$ will therefore also hold " for all $x$ belonging to  $A$" .
- The aim of this procedure is to use " universal generalization" at the end of the proof. As you can see, the goal here is to end with :

> " ***for all x,*** if $x$ is an element of $A$, then $x$ is an element of $B$"